# count char of TextArea (retrieved from database)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically creating combination of `textarea` and `label`, each combination having different ids. e.g: `text-1`, `text-2` .... for `textarea` and `lab-1`, `lab-2`, .... for `label`s.

Each `label` displays the number of characters in each `textarea`. I am doing this by using following piece of code.

```
function updateCount(textAreaId, labelId) {
    var cs = $('#'+textAreaId).val().length;
    $('#'+ labelId').text(cs);
}
```

Calling above function `onkeyUp` and `onKeyDown` on `textarea` and its working fine.

In some of the `textareas` I am filling the data from the users last submission from database, In that case it shows default length as **0**  till some key in not pressed in the `textarea`.

I want that as soon as page loads.

Comment: Can you show the keyUp event?

Comment: updateCount(textAreaId, labelId) is called on both keyDown as well as keyUp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually trigger `keyup`

```
$('textarea[id^="text-"]').keyup();
```

Make sure to place this line after binding the `keyup` events to all `textareas`

Answer (score 0):

On page load, get the value of the textareas where the value has been added. Get the length of the value, and subtract the length from the maximum length.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var length = $('textarea').val().length;
        Maxmlength = maxmlength - length;
      $('span').text(Maxmlength); //element to display the remaiing character.


});
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>

     $( document ).ready(function() {
        var textAreaId="textArea1";
        $('#'+textAreaId).keyup(function() {
        updateCount(textAreaId, labelId);
       });
    });

    </script>
```